# Compare date range and restrict dates beyond 3 months using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Have two dropdowns, API gives some date options(only months and followed by year eg: MAY-19) for start date and end date periods. Here need to restrict 3 months range. If beyond 3 months not allowed. Could you please give some idea  how to achieve this.

Please have look reference [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-validations-reactive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fformreactive%2Fformreactive.component.ts)

[image]

Comment: Please provide relevant code in the question itself, not only on an external site like Stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

Create a model months array:

```
months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

checkValidMonth(startDate: string, endDate: string): boolean {
  startDate = startDate.substr(0,3);
  endDate = endDate.substring(0,3);
  console.log(Math.abs(this.months.indexOf(startDate) -  this.months.indexOf(endDate)) <= 3)
  return Math.abs(this.months.indexOf(startDate) -  this.months.indexOf(endDate)) <= 3
}
```

HTML:

```
<p *ngIf="checkValidMonth(form.get('startDate').value, form.get('endDate').value)">**Months have to be 3 apart</p>
```

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-validations-reactive-j4uykk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fformreactive%2Fformreactive.component.ts